# Perforce: How to create a list of files from a changelist?

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, perforce

I want to create a list of files from a `changelist` in Perforce. I am using command line to open files for adding (`mark for add`) and deleting (`mark for delete`) into a `changelist`, I successfully created them and now I want these `changelist`'s to be in a list. Is there a Perforce command for it? How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a pending changelist, use the `p4 opened` command.  The `-c` flag lets you limit it to a specific changelist (including the "default changelist", which is really "files that are open on this client but not in a changelist yet").

```
C:\Perforce\test>p4 opened
//stream/main/bar#2 - integrate change 118 (text+S3)
//stream/main/foo#3 - edit default change (text)

C:\Perforce\test>p4 opened -c default
//stream/main/foo#3 - edit default change (text)
```

If you want just the filenames you can do something like:

```
C:\Perforce\test>p4 -F %depotFile% opened -c default
//stream/main/foo
```

For a submitted changelist, I like the `p4 files` command better than `p4 describe` because the output is easier to parse:

```
C:\Perforce\test>p4 files @=117
//stream/main/mob/nextproject/custom/configuration#2 - integrate change 117 (text)
```

Comment: I was about to make my own answer the accepted answer. But I tried `p4 opened` and the output is really better than what `p4 describe` does. Thanks

Comment: what does -F %depotFile% do?  I cannot find it in p4 -h.  And when I try to use it, I get an error: Path 'd:\xxx\xxx\xxx\xx\opened' is not under client's root 'd:\yyyy\yyyyy'.

Comment: Some good background info on `-F` (an undoc flag) in this blog post: https://web.archive.org/web/20131101013248/http://www.perforce.com/blog/130826/fun-formatting  The error you're hitting sounds like the result of a typo or maybe a config problem, but it's impossible to debug with the output obfuscated (are you really getting local paths instead of depot paths???).  I recommend contacting Perforce support or posting on their official forums so someone can help you debug.

Answer (score 2):

If ever someone bumps into the same situation. You can use `p4 describe` to get the list of files in your `changelist`. The only backdown here is that you can't use this for the `default changelist`, you need to have a `numbered changelist` in your Perforce.

```
p4 describe changelist_number
```

or if you want to generate a file after this list

```
p4 describe changelist_number > list.txt
```